# Transfering a variable from one html document to another with a popup-window in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

So I have a main html-document called `commit_PNG.html` and in this document i have two simple string variables i want to use in the other html-document called `popup.html`. At the moment i have a function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PopUpFenster(id) {          
        myWindow = window.open('popup.html?id='+id, 'Info window', 'height=350, width=800');
    }
</script>
```

In the second html-document I want to work with the string variables. I need a solution that work something like this in `popup.html`:

```
var string1 = "http://www.test.com/"+ commit_PNG.stringvariable1;
var string2 = "http://www.test.com/"+ commit_PNG.stringvariable2;
```

I'm not sure but I either need to take them directly from `commit_PNG.html` or parse them someone with the `window.open()` method.

Comment: So do you want to pass string1 and string2 to popup window?

Comment: Not directly in the popup window. I want to build with them, a dynamic URL in the second html-document. Later with that URL I get ressources which will be displayed in that popup window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hash part to transfer a JSON object like this:

In `commit_PNG.html`:

```
var myStrings = {
 str1:"my first str",
 str2:"my second str"
}

 function PopUpFenster(id) {  
        var myUrl = "popup.html?id="+id+"#"+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myStrings));

        window.open(myUrl , "Info window", "height=350, width=800");
    }
```

Then in your `popup.html` Just do:

```
var myData = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash.substring(1)));
alert(myData.str1 + " " + myData.str2);
```

It's a great way to pass date in a url. You get to pass a JSON object and using stringify with encodeURIComponent makes it a safe string for the URL.
Using the hash part, makes sure it's not sent to the server.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I edited a little bit, like a missing `=`.
Thanks for the fast anwser!

Answer (score 1):

> commit_PNG.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getVariables(){
       return {
          stringvariable1: 'v1',
          stringvariable2: 'v2'
       };
    }

    function PopUpFenster(id) {          
        myWindow = window.open('popup.html?id='+id, 'Info window', 'height=350, width=800');
    }
</script>
```

> popup.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var parentWindow = window.opener;
   var variables = parentWindow.getVariables();

    var string1 = "http://www.test.com/"+ variables.stringvariable1;
    var string2 = "http://www.test.com/"+ variables.stringvariable2;
</script>
```